# How can I copy a DVD to another DVD using a single DVD drive?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, compact-disc

I need to copy a DVD to another DVD, but I have only a single DVD drive.

How can I accomplish this? I tried copying files to the desktop and then to another DVD. It didn't work out.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are many ways to copy DVDs and many different programs out there to help with copying DVDs. Since you are using Windows 7 and Windows 7 comes with DVD burning software, I'll show you how to use the software that comes with Windows 7.The steps you took to copy the dvd should have worked. Once you copied all the files to the desktop, put in a blank DVD. If an AutoPlay box opens up with options, you can select "Burn files to disk using windows explorer." If the box does not show up after putting in the blank DVD, you can open up windows Explorer and click on the DVD drive on the lower left side.
[image]

You can leave the setting as "With a CD/DVD player" if you want since it is compatible with older computers. Click Next.

Now drag and drop all the files from your desktop into the explorer window. Then click "Burn to disc." Another window will open up, just click next. If you get any error messages, please update your question with the error message.
[image]

Comment: Please note that this will not produce a 1-to-1 copy of the DVD. Bootable DVD's for instance, will need to be copied by cloning the DVD (as opposed to just copying files). Personally, I use ImgBurn, like @Drooling_Sheep suggested.

Comment: I just tried to install ImgBurn but my virus scanner blocked it as it installs adware.

Answer (score 10):

If it's not a commercial movie DVD, you can use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) to rip the DVD to an ISO and burn it back to a second disc. If it's a commercial movie DVD, I'm not sure this is the place to ask that, if you get my drift.

Comment: it s just data. i m too old and rich to copy dvds

Answer (score 3):

[Burnaware](http://www.burnaware.com/) Free (downloadable from CNET) worked for me, in 2 steps:

1. Use the "Copy to Image" feature (creates the iso)
2. Use the "Burn Image" feature (select the created iso to create new CD/DVD)

Worked a treat no hassle. You might want to choose advanced setup instead of express since it installed some "clean your pc" bloat which i simply uninstalled from add/remove programs.

Note this was for a bootable Windows 7 install DVD and my system booted from the cloned disc fine into Windows setup.

Answer (score 2):

All good burning software allow to do on the fly copy (one reader + one writer) or delayed copy (one reader writer).

I usually use ISO recorder which allow to create ISO files, then burn ISO files.

Answer (score 1):

In almost all DVD burning software, you will find a option of copying the entire CD/DVD or something very similar. If you have only one DVD writer and you choose that option the program will make a file in its own format(*.iso, *.nrg, *.bin, etc.) on your hard disk and ask you to save this file on your specified location.

The size of this file will depend on the data on the DVD. After you save the file and process is complete, eject the original DVD and insert the blank DVD.

After that, double click the image file (*.iso or *.nrg) to open it in your default DVD burning software and just click on the burn option and you will get an exact copy of your disk.

However, if your DVD has copy protection you need some other software to decrypt that and then DVD creator software, and I can not give you more detail about this on this site because it is not legible I think.

Answer (score 1):

Using the built-in tools from Windows 7 is not that pretty or fast. There are better solutions offered by different companies.

If you would like a detailed guide of the steps and principles involved when copying discs, you can read this tutorial: [How to Copy a Disc (CD, DVD or Blu-Ray) in Windows](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-copy-disc-cd-dvd-or-blu-ray-windows).

It also presents some of the best free third-party programs that you can use to make quick copies: [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/en/home), [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/), [BurnAware Free](http://www.burnaware.com/burnaware_free.html), etc.